# Secure a route on the frontend AND the backend

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a Spring Boot + Angular app.

Using Guards i can make sure that only logged-in users can access my Angular application (via JWT). But that is just a frontend convenience that can be bypassed.

Can i additionally secure my app in the backend so that users that are not loggen cannot acces my app?
Is that even a thing?

Am i supposed to do that at all, or should i only really secure the backend API calls and make sure that users cannot access actual data that it has no access to?

Answer (score 1):

Main thing that you must apply is adding security to your endpoints. You must apply jwt based security to your spring boot api endpoints which are requiring security.Thus, unauthorized user who doesn't have jwt token can't access these endpoints. Otherwise, every user can access api's endpoints and database.This means the app is hacked.

Comment: I agree, it is very important to secure API endpoint so that users cannot get data they should not get. But i am asking something different. Lets say that typing in my browser "www.myApp.com/admin" opens a dashboard for admin users. With Guards i can forbid non-admins to open that page, the HTML itself. But that is only frontend convinience, not security. Is it possible to securely prevent non-admins to open that link using the backend?

Comment: When you use guard in angular you forbid user who doesn't have jwt token to access "www.myApp.com/admin" page. Anyone can't access this page but when you don't use jwt security in spring-boot endpoints, user who doesn't have jwt token can access this endpoint's data even if it can't reach "www.myApp.com/admin" page. In the .NET Core platform we perform this security with adding `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller methods. In Spring Boot achives this security with different ways. You can follow Spring Boot JWT based tutorials in order to achive this security.